# What is the best way to union all column values from multiple tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, union

Preface: I didn't design this database and I can't change it, I'm stuck with it until I can convince the client to rewrite it.

There are several dozen tables that all have a LastInvoiceDate column in them, I'm looking for a way to create a view or something similar that will union them all together such that I get this:

| Tablename | LastInvoiceDate |
| --- | --- |
| FooTable | 2022-01-01 |
| BarTable | 2021-12-31 |
| FooBarTable | 2020-06-01 |
| NewlyAddedTable | 2022-07-14 |

The problem is that new tables can be added at any time so it needs to be dynamic to construct this based on what is currently in the database. Anyway to accomplish this in MySQL (v5.6.51)? Much obliged!

Comment: Note you are using a version of MySQL that is over a year past its end of life. There are an unknown number of security vulnerabilities in that software, and by policy they will never be fixed. This is a safety risk, like storing a bin of sawdust and oily rags in your garage.

Comment: Believe me, I understand the constraint. I've worked for employers who didn't see the need to upgrade. That doesn't make it untrue that it's a risk.

Comment: The title says all columns from multiple tables and example output shows 1 column and 1 row from multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

You can't make any SQL query that queries from a "dynamic" set of tables. The set of tables must be explicit and fixed in the query at the time it is parsed.

But you can make an SQL query that examines the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to produce a string, which is itself an SQL query against all the tables. I.e. a two-step process.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
 CONCAT(
   'SELECT ', QUOTE(TABLE_NAME), ' AS Tablename,'
   'LastInvoiceDate ',
   'FROM `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME, '`'
 )
 SEPARATOR ' UNION '
) AS _query
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'LastInvoiceDate';
```